# Disable "resume from suspend" through keypress

Tags: linux, arch-linux, power-management

After suspending my laptop, it usually wakes up when I press:

1. any key
2. power button

How can I disable option 1, so that it just resumes when pressing the power button?

I am using a Lenovo Yoga 3-14.

Comment: Make and model of your laptop? This is hardware related. You might be able to change the setting in the BIOS but probably not. This is just the way your laptop behaves.

Comment: @Appleoddity I added that information, didn't expect its hardware related, thanks!